# Error: 'this.proxy' is null or not an object in EXTJS

Tags: extjs, extjs3

When i ran this EXTJS code,i got an error **'this.proxy' is null or not an object**. Can you help me out regarding this,plzz ?

```
var myData = [
                   ['J', 'MD'],
                   ['A', 'VA'],
                   ['S', 'DC'],
                   ['M', 'DE'],
                   ['B', 'NJ'],
                   ['N', 'CA'],
                   ['S', 'RT'],
                   ['S', 'CG']
                 ];
 var store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
        totalProperty : 8,
        autoLoad : {
            params : {
                start : 0,
                limit : 4
            }
        },
        fields : [ {
            name : 'fullName'
        }, {
            name : 'state'
        } ]
    });

 store.loadData(myData);
 var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store : store,
    columns : [ {
        id : 'fullName',
        header : "FullName",
        width : 160,
        sortable : true,
        dataIndex : 'fullName'
    }, {
        header : "State",
        width : 75,
        sortable : true,
        dataIndex : 'state'
    } ],
    stripeRows : true,
    autoExpandColumn : 'fullName',
    height : 350,
    width : 600,
    title : 'Array Grid',
    bbar : new Ext.PagingToolbar({
        store : store,
        pageSize : 4,
        displayInfo : true
    }),
    viewConfig : {
        forceFit : true
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot at the same time use `memory proxy` and `autoLoad` config as well as `store.load`. `autoLoad` config and `store.load` can only be used with proxies that are intended for actual loading of data like `Ajax` proxy.

However, you can use [`Direct`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.proxy.Direct) proxy. In this case you will have to create your `direct-function` which will play role of `server-side`.

```
var myData = [
['J', 'MD'],
...
];
var myDirectfn = function(opts, fn, proxy){
  var start = opts.start, end = opts.page*opts.limit;
  var data = [];
  if (end > myData.length)
    end = myData.length;
  for (var i = start; i < end; i++)
    data.push(myData[i]);
  fn(0, {status: true, result: data});
};

//Why am I doing this? I don't know, but otherwise store will throw exception
myDirectfn.directCfg={method : {}};

var store = new Ext.data.Store({
  //totalProperty : 8, 
  pageSize: 4,
  proxy: {
    type: 'direct',
    directFn: myDirectfn,
    reader: {type: 'array'}
  },
  fields : [ {name : 'fullName'}, {name : 'state'} ]
});
```

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/TfXUM/) is fiddle to play arround with.

**UPDATE**

For extjs3 Direct Proxy method would look like this:

```
var myDirectfn = function(opts, fn, proxy) {
    var start = opts.start,
        end = opts.limit+opts.start,
        data = [];
    if (end > myData.length) end = myData.length;
    for (var i = start; i < end; i++)
        data.push(myData[i]);
    data.total = myData.length;
    fn(data, {
        status: true,
        result: data
    });
};
myDirectfn.directCfg = {
    method: {len:1}
};
var store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    proxy: new Ext.data.DirectProxy({
        directFn: myDirectfn
    }),
    fields: [{
        name: 'fullName'},
    {
        name: 'state'}]
})

store.load({params: {start: 0, limit: 4}});
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tmsR8/1/). And also it appears that you can utilise memory proxy with `load`ing by using [this plugin](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?71532-Ext.ux.data.PagingStore-v0.5)

Comment: @ Molecule: Thank u very much.But when i execute the above code with the direct function in ECLIPSE,it displays an error as 'Object doesn't support this property or method'.

Comment: Error Detail:line 7,char 23481 in 'ext-all.js' file

Comment: @Jackie, it won't be possible to locate where the problem is if you are using 'ext-all.js'. Try to replace it with 'ext-all-debug.js' version. Then locate where is error arising (in what method of what component) and tell me the result.

Comment: @ Molecule: I think there is a difference in EXTJS version i guess.I'm using EXTJS version 3.So,can u help me with which it supports the 3rd version ?

Comment: @Jackie, oops. Yes it can be true. My example is for ExtJS4. Sorry, I'll try to rebuild it for ExtJS3

Comment: @ Molecule: U r xactly rite.U got my point,Thank u.Looking forward for ur reply.

Comment: @Jackie, I've found [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/tmsR8/1/). And also it appears that you can utilise memory proxy with `load`ing by using [this plugin](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?71532-Ext.ux.data.PagingStore-v0.5)

Comment: @Jackie, I don't know then. Kind of strange behavior. The last suggestion: try to wrap the code in `Ext.onReady(function(){/* code is here*/});`

Comment: @ Molecule : No issues in the fiddle,everything works fine.But can u just try these scenarios,1st Scenario:Include all files in a single folder (Say on desktop),'ext-all.js','ext-base.js','ext-all.css','example.js'(this includes the above code in Ext.onReady(function(){/* code is here*/}); & 'example.html' file to call all other files.Observe the output. Second Scenario: Replace the 'ext-all.js' file with 'ext-all-debug.js',now observer the difference.Now tell me what exactly it's ? what do u say about this ?