# How to add paging to extjs 4 grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a store like this which i used for a extjs grid

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad : true,
    fields   : [
        {name: 'item_code', mapping: 'item_code', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'quantity', mapping: 'quantity', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'description', mapping: 'description', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'selling_price', mapping: 'selling_price', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'discount', mapping: 'discount', type: 'string'}
    ],
    storeId  : 'available_products',
    proxy    : {
        type            : 'ajax',
        actionMethods   : 'POST',
        url             : 'http://192.168.1.6/transactions/distribution_store',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        }
    }
});
```

I want to add a paging to grid but i want it like this

first load all the data with json and paging those results at client side without sending server requests.

is it possible?
how to do this?

Regards

Comment: paging functionality (paging toolbar) is independent of 'records loading' (store) functionality. you can setup paging toolbar with a local store. it doesnt have to be a remote/direct store. so instead of defining proxy in your store, load records outside the store and then call store.loadData() just once to load your store. after that paging toolbar will work off of records in store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For loading all data use

```
var myData = [];
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://192.168.1.6/transactions/distribution_store',
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(response){
        myData = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

When all data is loaded you can utilize `directFn` config for emulating paging functionality. Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858513/error-this-proxy-is-null-or-not-an-object-in-extjs/6860463#6860463) for more info. And check out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/TfXUM/) too.

### UPDATE

> the solution doesn't work for ext js 4.1.1 . Can u provide an example for this version?
>
> Doesn't work for ExtJS 4.2 either.

`directFn` solution always seemed like a hack to me. Since 4.0.7 there is no need to use `directFn`. Instead use [Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy). The demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/7TJUn/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer,i tried like this but nothing is loading maybe its due to my json output,  my json output is like  {"data":[{"item_code":"ASCM72X36","quantity":4},{"item_code":"ASCM72X60","quantity":4}]}

Comment: @Gihan, what part doesn't work? Loading from the server via Ajax.request or populating the grid with loaded data?

Comment: populating grid with data. seems like a decoding problem

Comment: @Gihan, I've updated [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/TfXUM/10/) specificaly for your json output.

Comment: the solution doesn't work for ext js 4.1.1 . Can u provide an example for this version?